# return only vevo videos

Tags: ios, video, youtube-api

I have an iOS app that goes to youtube and gets videos. I want to make it to where it only returns videos from a vevo channel. What is the API link I would use in order to do this? This is my data link:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/%@?alt=json
```

## How would I change this link to get vevo-only videos.

Also, if there isn't a way for the above, is there a way to make it return a query with a permanent string? e.g. q=Hozier + "Audio"

Hozier = What the user inputed

Audio = The permanent string.

Essentially whatever the user inputs is followed by audio